# Prove via mathematical induction that $4n < 2^n$ for all $ n≥5$.

Tags: inequality, induction

I did the following base case $n = 5$
$$\begin{align*}
    4(5) &\lt 2 ^5\\
    20 &\lt 32
\end{align*}$$
So true.

$$\begin{align*}    
4n &\lt 2^n\\
n &\lt 2^{n-2}\\
\log_2(n)+2 &\lt n
\end{align*}$$
But I don't think this is right. Where do I add in the $(n+1)$.

Comment: Do you really mean "for all $n\lt 5$"? That would require you to check four cases, which does not require induction. Did you mean "for all $n\geq 5$" instead?

Comment: yes thats what i meant n≥5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The induction base is correct.

For the inductive step, we *assume* that the result holds for $n$, with $n\geq 5$; that is, are assuming that
$$4n\lt 2^n,\qquad n\geq 5.$$
We want to prove that, under this assumption, $4(n+1)\lt 2^{n+1}$.

**Hint the first.** $4(n+1) = 4n+4 \lt 2^n+4$, with the last step using the induction hypothesis.

**Hint the second.** $2^{n+1} = 2\times 2^n = 2^n+2^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint

So you want to show for $n>4$,
$$4n<2^n \implies 4n+4 < 2^n+2^n$$

Answer (score 1):

If $4n<2^n$ then $4n+4<2^n+4<2^n+2^n=2^{n+1}$ (the second inequality hold since $2^n\geq4 $ for $n\geq 2$). It follows that $4(n+1)<2^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think might work:

Step 1: Base case. You've done this.

Step 2. Assume $4k<2^k$ for arbitrary k contained in the naturals. You can do this because your base case proves the assumption true for at least one k. That is, you've proved this true for k=5.

Step 3. Prove this holds for $n=k+1$.

$$4k<2^{k}$$ 
$$8k<2^k*2$$
$$8k<2^{k+1}$$

It is obvious that: $4k+1<8k<2^{K+1}$ for $K>4$

And therefore, by induction, that $4n<2^n$ for all n belonging to the naturals where n>4.

That is my attempt. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Given $5\leq{n}$

Assume $4n<2^n$

Prove $4(n+1)<2^{n+1}$:

- $4(n+1)=4n+4$
- $4n+4<2^n+4$ `assumption used here`
- $2^n+4<2^n+32$
- $2^n+32=2^n+2^5$
- $2^n+2^5\leq2^n+2^n$ `given fact used here`
- $2^n+2^n=2^{n+1}$