# Proving inequality $4n<2^n$ using induction all natural numbers that's greater than or equal to 5

Tags: inequality, induction

Using mathematical induction, prove that $n\le5: 4n<2^n$

base case:
$4(5) < 2^5$
$20 < 32$
Correct

I need help with the inductive process

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131036/prove-via-mathematical-induction-that-4n-2n-for-all-n%E2%89%A55) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/131036).